# how to make the balance remain stored in the RFID 522?

Tags: c++, arduino, esp32, arduino-uno, rfid

I have a problem. I have an RFID 522 that I use to communicate via "Serial." When I swipe the card, it stores a value of $100, and every time I swipe the card again, it consistently increases by +$100. However, when I reset the Arduino controller (ESP32) and swipe the card again, the value reverts to $100 instead of continuing to accumulate with the previous balance. I would like to know how to permanently store that balance on the card and use it whenever I want.
The code works, but it only has that detail of not permanently storing that value on the card.

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <MFRC522.h>

constexpr uint8_t RST_PIN = 17;  // Configurable, see typical pin layout above
constexpr uint8_t SS_PIN = 5;    // Configurable, see typical pin layout above
int currentBalance = 0;
MFRC522 mfrc522(SS_PIN, RST_PIN);  // Create MFRC522 instance
char c;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);  // Initialize serial communications with the PC
  SPI.begin();         // Init SPI bus
  mfrc522.PCD_Init();  // Init MFRC522 card
}

void loop() {
  // Keep the program in a continuous loop, waiting for the card to be swiped
  int newCard = Read();  // Attempt to read the card

  if (newCard != 0) {
    currentBalance += 100;  // Increment the balance by 100
    Write(currentBalance);  // Write the new balance to the card
    Serial.print("New balance: ");
    Serial.println(currentBalance);
  }
}

void Write(int balance) {
  // Prepare key - all keys are set to FFFFFFFFFFFFh at chip delivery from the factory.
  MFRC522::MIFARE_Key key;
  for (byte i = 0; i < 6; i++) key.keyByte[i] = 0xFF;

  // Look for new cards
  while (!mfrc522.PICC_IsNewCardPresent()) {
    //return;
  }

  // Select one of the cards
  while (!mfrc522.PICC_ReadCardSerial()) {
    //return;
  }

  Serial.print(F("Card UID:"));  //Dump UID
  for (byte i = 0; i < mfrc522.uid.size; i++) {
    Serial.print(mfrc522.uid.uidByte[i] < 0x10 ? " 0" : " ");
    Serial.print(mfrc522.uid.uidByte[i], HEX);
  }
  Serial.print(F(" PICC type: "));  // Dump PICC type
  MFRC522::PICC_Type piccType = mfrc522.PICC_GetType(mfrc522.uid.sak);
  Serial.println(mfrc522.PICC_GetTypeName(piccType));

  byte buffer[34];
  byte block = 1;

  sprintf((char *)buffer, "%d", balance);
  Serial.println(balance);

  MFRC522::StatusCode status;

  status = mfrc522.PCD_Authenticate(MFRC522::PICC_CMD_MF_AUTH_KEY_A, block, &key, &(mfrc522.uid));
  if (status != MFRC522::STATUS_OK) {
    Serial.print(F("PCD_Authenticate() failed: "));
    Serial.println(mfrc522.GetStatusCodeName(status));
    return;
  } else {
    Serial.println(F("PCD_Authenticate() success: "));
  }

  // Write block
  status = mfrc522.MIFARE_Write(block, buffer, 16);
  if (status != MFRC522::STATUS_OK) {
    Serial.print(F("MIFARE_Write() failed: "));
    Serial.println(mfrc522.GetStatusCodeName(status));
    return;
  } else {
    Serial.println(F("MIFARE_Write() success: "));
  }

  Serial.println(" ");
  mfrc522.PICC_HaltA();       // Halt PICC
  mfrc522.PCD_StopCrypto1();  // Stop encryption on PCD
}

int Read() {
  MFRC522::MIFARE_Key key;
  for (byte i = 0; i < 6; i++) key.keyByte[i] = 0xFF;

  //some variables we need
  byte block;
  byte len;
  MFRC522::StatusCode status;

  //-------------------------------------------

  // Look for new cards
  while (!mfrc522.PICC_IsNewCardPresent()) {
    //return;
  }

  // Select one of the cards
  while (!mfrc522.PICC_ReadCardSerial()) {
    //return;
  }

  Serial.println(F("**Card Detected:**"));

  //-------------------------------------------

  mfrc522.PICC_DumpDetailsToSerial(&(mfrc522.uid));  //dump some details about the card

  //mfrc522.PICC_DumpToSerial(&(mfrc522.uid));      //uncomment this to see all blocks in hex
  len = 18;
  //---------------------------------------- GET LAST NAME

  byte buffer2[18];
  block = 1;

  status = mfrc522.PCD_Authenticate(MFRC522::PICC_CMD_MF_AUTH_KEY_A, 1, &key, &(mfrc522.uid));  //line 834
  if (status != MFRC522::STATUS_OK) {
    Serial.print(F("Authentication failed: "));
    Serial.println(mfrc522.GetStatusCodeName(status));
    return currentBalance;
  }

  status = mfrc522.MIFARE_Read(block, buffer2, &len);
  if (status != MFRC522::STATUS_OK) {
    Serial.print(F("Reading failed: "));
    Serial.println(mfrc522.GetStatusCodeName(status));
    return currentBalance;
  }

  String text = "";
  for (uint8_t i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
    text += buffer2[i];
  }

  Serial.println(text);

  int currentBalance = text.toInt();
  currentBalance = 1;


  //----------------------------------------

  Serial.println(F("\n**End Reading**\n"));

  delay(1000);  //change value if you want to read cards faster

  mfrc522.PICC_HaltA();
  mfrc522.PCD_StopCrypto1();
  return currentBalance;
}
```

I tried to create new functions, variables, and other things, but unfortunately, I couldn't. I used AI and several forums, but they didn't yield results, so I went back to my base code.

Comment: If an answer solves your problem you might think about accepting it and/or upcoting it. If it is incomplete, you can ask for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Your variables are a mess.

```cpp
int currentBalance = 0;  // << global variable
...
void loop() {
  // Keep the program in a continuous loop, waiting for the card to be swiped
  int newCard = Read();  // Attempt to read the card

  if (newCard != 0) {
    currentBalance += 100;  // Increment the balance by 100
...
  }
}
```

Here, you asign the balance read from the card into `newCard` but don't use it. Instead you always increment the global variable. Whatever you read from the card is lost here.
Try

```cpp
    currentBalance = newCard + 100;  // Increment the balance by 100
```

instead.

In your `Read` function you totally get lost:

```cpp
int Read() {
...
  if (status != MFRC522::STATUS_OK) {
    Serial.print(F("Authentication failed: "));
    Serial.println(mfrc522.GetStatusCodeName(status));
    return currentBalance;
  }
```

In case of an error you return the current value of the global variable.
In your loop that is interpreted as a new value and the balance will be incremented.
I am not sure if that is intention.
I would assume an error means you cannot increment anything.
You should return `0` instead.

```cpp
...
// If there is no error found above, we get here:
  int currentBalance = text.toInt();
  currentBalance = 1;  // Discard value from the card.
...
  return currentBalance;
}
```

This creates a new local variable shadowing the global variable. Whatever you assign here will not end up in the global variable.
Furthermore, whatever you have read from the card, is also lost because you immediately overwrite the value with a `1`. Remove that line.

Mixing usage of global variable and local variable with same name is very confusing and should never be done.